# How to center a child element of a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, element, center

I have a form that I create dynamically in javascript and end as follows:

```
mybreak=document.createElement("p");
form.appendChild(mybreak);

var buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
buttonElement.setAttribute("type","submit");
buttonElement.innerHTML="<img src=\"images/lock.png\"  width=\"80\" height=\"80\" alt=\"Submit\"/>Try it!";
form.appendChild(buttonElement);
```

This results in my submit button being left-aligned on the page.  I would like it centered on the page instead.  Adding  in innerHTML centers the text within the button, which is not what I want.  Adding an align = center attribute to my child has the same effect.

What's the trick I am missing here to have that submit button nicely centered on the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel odd answering my own question, but what I was after was understanding how to center my submit button strictly from javascript since I was creating the form dynamically and only needed that last submit button centered.

The solution is to simply modify my original code as follows:

```
 newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 newDiv.setAttribute("align","center");

 var buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
 buttonElement.setAttribute("text-align","center");
 buttonElement.setAttribute("type","submit");
 buttonElement.innerHTML="<img src=\"images/lock.png\"  width=\"80\" height=\"80\" alt=\"Submit\"/>Try it!";
 newDiv.appendChild(buttonElement);
 form.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some CSS to the `<p>` that holds the button.

```
p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am still unclear about how I can accomplish this from javascript, since I am creating the form dynamically.

Comment: Just link to a stylesheet or add the style in the head of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
#element_containing_submit_btn { text-align: center; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/egd9G/